# Finding the number of all the shortest paths between two nodes in directed unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I need help to finding the number of all the shortest paths between two nodes in an directed unweighted graph.

I am able to find one of the shortest paths using BFS algorithm, but i dont know how to find all the shortest paths.

Any idea of the algorithm / pseudocode I could use?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by remembering how many paths are leading to each node, and when discovering a new node - summarize that number.

For simplicity, let's assume you have regular BFS algorithm, that whenever you use an edge `(u,v)`, calls `visit(u,v,k)`, where:

```
u - the source node of the edge
v - the target node of the edge
k - the distance from the original source to u
```

In addition to this, assume you have a mapping `d:(vertex,distance)->#paths`.

This is basically a map (or 2D matrix) that it's key is a pair of vertex and an integer - distance, and its value is the number of shortest paths leading from the source, to that vertex, with distance `k`.

It is easy to see that for each vertex v:

```
d[v,k] = sum { d[u,k-1] | for all edges (u,v) } 
d[source,0] = 0
```

And now, you can easily find the number of shortest paths of length `k` leading to each node.

**Optimization:**

You can see that "number of shortest paths of length k" is redundant, you actually need only one value of `k` for each vertex. This requires some book-keeping, but saves you some space.

Good luck!

Comment: I am completely lost on this one. Can anyone provide a pseudo code?

Answer (score 2):

The first idea that come to my mind is the next:

Let's name start vertex as `s` and end vertex as `e`.

We can store two arrays: `D` and `Q`. `D[i]` is a length of the shortest path from `s` to `i` and `Q[i]` is a number of shortest paths between `s` and `i`.

How can we recalculate these arrays?

First of all, lets set `D[s] = 0` and `Q[s] = 1`. Then we can use well-known `bfs`:

```
    while queue with vertexes is not empty

    get v from queue

    set v as visited

    for all u, there's an edge from v to u
        if u is not visited yet
            D[u] = D[v] + 1
            Q[u] = Q[v]
            push u into the queue
        else if D[v] + 1 == D[u]
            Q[u] += Q[v]
```

The answer is `Q[e]`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your breadth first search to keep going until it starts finding longer paths, rather than stopping and returning just the first one.

Comment: Why do you think it will work? there could be exponential number of shortest paths.

Comment: More explicitly, consider a graph: `s0->s1, s0->s2, s1->s3, s2->s3`. There are two shortest paths here. Now, if you add `s3->s4, s3->s5, s4->s6, s5->s6` there are 4 shortest paths. Adding one more such part, will again double the number of shortest paths, and so on and so on.... BFS will fail to find the number of shortest paths if you simply "continue until a longer path is found".

Comment: @amit I understood the question to be to actually find the paths, not just count them.  If there are a lot of paths, this is necessarily a lot of work.

Comment: `I understood the question to be to actually find the paths`. Well, `keep going until it starts finding longer paths` won't find all paths. BFS traverses each node once (even with this modification), and will fail to find paths in graphs like the counter example I previously gave.